# __get magic method - how to throw and catch error for property overloading?

Tags: php, try-catch, magic-methods

I define what happens when a non-existent property is being accessed by taking advantage of the `__get` magic method.

So if `$property->bla` does not exist I will get `null`.

```
return (isset($this->$name)) ? $this->$name : null;
```

But I want to throw and catch the error for `$property->bla->bla` when I know that `$property->bla` does not exist.

with `return (isset($this->$name)) ? $this->$name : null;` I will get this error below,

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in...
```

So I use `throw and catch` error in my class,

class property 
{

```
public function __get($name)
{
    //return (isset($this->$name)) ? $this->$name : null;

    try {
        if (!isset($this->$name)) {
          throw new Exception("Property $name is not defined");
        }
        return $this->$name;
      }
      catch (Exception $e) {

        return $e->getMessage(); 
      }
}
```

}

But the result is not what I want because it `throw` the error message `("Property $name is not defined")` instead of `null` for `$property->bla`.

How can I make it to throw error message **only** for `$property->bla->bla`, `$property->bla->bla->bla`, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, when you calling `$property->foo->bar` and `$property` class have magic __get method, you can verify only `foo` property and throw error only for it.

But if your `foo` is also an instance of the same class (or similar class with the same magic `__get` method) you can also verify `bar` property and throw the next error.

For example:

```
class magicLeaf {
    protected $data;
    public function __construct($hashTree) {
        $this->data = $hashTree;
    }
    // Notice that we returning another instance of the same class with subtree
    public function __get($k) {
        if (array_key_exists($k, $this->data)) {
             throw new Exception ("Property $name is not defined");
        }
        if (is_array($this->data[$k])) { // lazy convert arrays to magicLeaf classes
            $this->data[$k] = new self($this->data[$k]);
        }
        return $this->data[$k];
    }
 }
```

And now just example of using it:

```
$property = new magicLeaf(array(
    'foo' => 'root property',
    'bar' => array(
        'yo' => 'Hi!',
        'baz' => array(
            // dummy
        ),
    ),
));
$property->foo; // should contain 'root property' string
$property->bar->yo; // "Hi!"
$property->bar->baz->wut; // should throw an Exception with "Property wut is not defined"
```

So now you can see how to made it almost like you want.

Now just modify a little your `__construct` and magic `__get` methods and add new param to know where we are at each level:

```
...
    private $crumbs;
    public function __construct($hashTree, $crumbs = array()) {
        $this->data = $hashTree;
        $this->crumbs = $crumbs;
    }
    public function __get($k) {
        if (array_key_exists($k, $this->data)) {
             $crumbs = join('->', $this->crumbs);
             throw new Exception ("Property {$crumbs}->{$name} is not defined");
        }
        if (is_array($this->data[$k])) { // lazy convert arrays to magicLeaf classes
            $this->data[$k] = new self($this->data[$k], $this->crumbs + array($k));
        }
        return $this->data[$k];
    }
...
```

I think it should works like you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Within the scope of the `__get()` function, you only know about `$property->blah`. You have no clue what comes after it, because that's the functionality of the language.

Note the order of evaluations on `$foo = $property->blah->blah2->blah3`:

1. `$temp1 = $property->blah;`
2. `$temp1 = $temp1->blah2;`
3. `$foo   = $temp1->blah3;`

Of course, `$temp1` is fictitious, but this is essentially what happens in the execution of that statement. Your `__get()` call is only aware of the first call in that list, and nothing more. What you can do is handle the error on the calling side, with [`property_exists()`](http://php.net/property_exists) or check for `null`:

```
$temp = $property->blah;
if( $temp === null || !property_exists( $temp, 'blah2')) {
    throw new Exception("Bad things!");
}
```

Note that `property_exists()` will fail if the object returned in `$temp` also relies on `__get()`, but that was not clear in the OP.